# bbfreeze import function from compiled library

Tags: python, raspbian

Using Python 2.7 on Raspbian with bbfreeze, can I compile a single module, then import it in another script that is not obfuscated?

Something like this:

```
bbfreeze mylibrary.py (that contain function())
```

Then:

```
>>> import mylibrary as p
>>> p.function()
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on Windows. I'd expect it, or small variation, will work on linux but I don't have access to a linux box to try it.

Create the application to be frozen with the following directory structure:

```
-- sample
    -- app
        - __init__.py
        - fns.py
    - main.py
    - setup.py
```

Code for each python file is:

**fns.py**

```
"""Place functions you want to access from the frozen app here"""
def accessible():
    print "This function is accessible"
```

**main.py**

```
import app.fns

def inaccessible():
    print "This function is inaccessible; AFAIK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inaccessible()
    app.fns.accessible()
```

**bb_setup.py**

```
from bbfreeze import Freezer

f = Freezer(distdir="frozen")
f.addScript("main.py")
f()
```

Freezing the app results in the directory frozen. You can now access the functions in **fns.py** from the 'frozen' application with code like:

**useFrozenCode.py**

```
import sys

# Add the path to the frozen applications app module to the python path
sys.path.append("C:\\no_backup\\personal\\sample\\frozen\\library.zip")

import app.fns

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Calling a routine from a frozen application"
    app.fns.accessible()
```

I don't know of anyway to call the function **inaccessible** in main.py.